# mysqli_affected_rows always returns 0

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a function to delete one of the users in my database with the following code, how ever the mysqli_affected_rows always returns 0 ?

```
$query = "DELETE FROM taxaapp_users WHERE id = $clientId AND grp = $grp";
    $response['errorMsg1'] = $query;
    if (sqlQuery($query)){
        $response['success'] = "testing " . mysqli_affected_rows($con);

    } else {
        $result = sqlQuery("SELECT id FROM ");
        $response['errorMsg'] = "Der er sket en fejl";
    }

function sqlQuery($query) {
    global $con;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    return mysqli_query($con, $query);
}
```

The correct user is being deleted when its run, if I change the $clientId to one that does not exist the query still returns true (probably right) and the mysqli_affected_rows returns 0 still.

Comment: Why are you executing the query twice?

Comment: execute your query at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you executing the query twice?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
return mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

The second time it won't delete anything, because it's already been delete by the first execution, so affected rows will be 0

Answer (score 0):

Don't execute twice.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM taxaapp_users WHERE id = '$clientId' AND grp = '$grp'";
    $response['errorMsg1'] = $query;
    if (sqlQuery($query)){
        $response['success'] = "testing " . mysqli_affected_rows($con);

    } else {
        $result = sqlQuery("SELECT id FROM ");
        $response['errorMsg'] = "Der er sket en fejl";
    }

function sqlQuery($query) {
    global $con;
    return mysqli_query($con, $query);
}
```

Comment: Hey, how sure are you that the `id` and `grp` are not of `Int` data type?

Comment: Here, no one can be sure. Better ask the OP to give DB structure. We are not writing full code. We give suggestions. How could we know what structure he is having ??@BlessedNerd

Answer (score 0):

You just need to execute query at once. because 0 is the result set of second query where you are using return in your function.